# Optimize MySQL insertion - insert multiple records with condition (per record)

Tags: mysql, query-performance

although not new to SQL, up until now I used the basic stuff - basic crud, joining tables etc. I have a special case now where I'm expecting a lot more insertions that goes something like this (pseudocode):

```
foreach(id_of_student in students){
    {class} = students[id_of_student].class;
    {grade} = students[id_of_student].grade;
    INSERT INTO grades (id_of_student,class,grade) VALUES({id_of_student},{class},{grade})
    WHERE grade.notSetManually=1 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
}
```

1. Of course I would like to not run it as a loop and access the db 50 times for each grade sheet (my app checks up to 50 grade sheets per minute). Can this be done in one big query, in a more optimized way? I saw that there is `LOOP` in mysql, but is it just syntactic sugar when it comes to the burden on the DB?
2. Another thing - this `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` means that as long as my key is `{id_of_student},{class}`, this will update and not add new line, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IODKU works well with `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO t
    (unique_key, counter, time)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        counter = VALUES(counter) + 1,
        time = NOW()
  SELECT unique_key, 1, NOW()
      FROM ...
```

Notes:

- Need unique key (or set of columns)
- See how a counter can be updated